# Is there an alternative to upgrade PHP 5.1.6 to 5.2.x on CentOS?

Tags: php, centos

I followed the [CentOS how-to](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/PHP_5.1_To_5.2) but always get this error:

```
http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/i386/repodata/filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 4] Socket Error: timed out
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/filelists.sqlite.bz2 from c5-testing: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running a `yum clean all` then rerun the install - though at first glance it looks like the mirror is having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a connection problem (to one of the mirrors)?

Could be a problem with the yum cache. I haven't had similar problems but found post regarding similar problems, where the tip was to try

yum clean metadata
and/or
yum remove yum-fastestmirror

You might want to read up on it mmore before trying though